# How can I use ngCordova File api to save JSON?

Tags: json, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to save JSON data in my Ionic app to the local device storage.  I would like to use the ngCordova File plugin.  I can't seem to find any tutorials or example apps that use the exact methods they have in the [docs](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/).

Has anyone used this plugin before to save JSON data?  How did you do it?

Answer (score 2):

ngCordova takes away a lot of the ugliness of writing files using the file writer API.

This example has been adapted from the [docs](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/), and uses `writeFile(path, file, data, replace)` where the path is defined by `cordova.file.DIRECTORY_TYPE`, file is a string name for the file, data is the *string* representation of the data (so we will use `JSON.stringify()`).  Replace is a boolean that will simply erase the existing contents of the file.

```
//Write using cordova.file.dataDirectory, see File System Layout section for more info
var json = {"test": "hello world"}
$cordovaFile.writeFile(cordova.file.dataDirectory, "hello.json", JSON.stringify(json), true)
  .then(function (success) {
    // success
  }, function (error) {
    // error
    console.log(error); //error mappings are listed in the documentation
  });
```

For a controller, supposing we are using controllerAs syntax it could look something like this:

```
angular.controller("...",['$cordovaFile' function ($cordovaFile) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.writeFile = function (fileName) {
    ionic.Platform.ready(function(){
      // will execute when device is ready, or immediately if the device is already ready.
      var json = {"test": "hello world"}
      $cordovaFile.writeFile(cordova.file.dataDirectory, "hello.json", JSON.stringify(json), true)
        .then(function (success) {
          // success
        }, function (error) {
          // error
          console.log(error); //error mappings are listed in the documentation
      });
    });
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Can you show me how you would add this to a controller as a function?  For example I want to call this function when the save button is clicked.  How would you add that?  And does this code have to be inside of a $ionicPlatform.ready() function to work?  [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32056322/cordovafile-method-does-nothing-when-called)  is the code I'm trying to use.